# What's the best source for learning how to create RESTful APIs in Java?

Tags: java, api, rest

I'm looking for a book or any other resource that will help me learn how to create RESTful APIs in Java. 
Looking on Amazon, I saw that there are [several solutions for RESTful Java](http://www.amazon.com/s?tag=ronin-20&index=blended&field-keywords=restful%20java), but I'm looking for the one that is tailored to a novice.

Looking forward to getting your advices/opinions, thanks!

Answer (score 84, accepted):

I don't think I can point to only one resource but I would take a path (which you can customize based on your level of understanding of REST). I'm somebody who would like to get my concepts real clear first and then think about the tools to implement the concepts.

- If you haven't read [chapter 5 of Roy Fielding's dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm), I'd start from there. It's an excellent piece of writing, and what better source to learn from than the master himself.
- Infoq is an excellent source for REST articles, helped me significantly, here is a [compilation of REST resources](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/emag-03-2010-rest). Also on Infoq read this [excellent article](http://www.infoq.com/articles/subbu-allamaraju-rest) by Allamaraju.
- If you are looking at books, the two that I liked so far: [RESTful Web Services Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596801688) and [RESTful Web Services](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529260)
- As you are looking for Java-based services -- I'd get familiar with [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) and/or [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy). Write as many small programs as you can, what's the best way to get familiarized.
- When you are at a point to try an exciting RESTful framework that's based on Hypermedia constraint I'd explore [Restfulie](http://restfulie.caelum.com.br/).

Obviously, I haven't provided a single resource, but something in the lines I've provided would serve well, IMO.

Comment: Thank you. Though "RESTFul Java with JAX-RS" is quite old and lot of things evolved current past, gives good insight on the concepts. As explained one need to go though multiple resources to get a good understanding on REST.

Comment: This is one of the best replies I have come across!!

Comment: I know this is an old question but the best resource I have found is [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xkKcdK1u95s&list=PLqq-6Pq4lTTZh5U8RbdXq0WaYvZBz2rbn). I find the best way to learn something is to code. This gives you a really good overview of REST and shows you how to code it so you can code along.

Answer (score 5):

I found [REST in Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805829) to be the best book covering different styles of REST architectures.  It's also far more practical in its advice than many other books (I wasn't impressed by RESTful Web Services as I think it lacks focus).

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation would be this one:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend this extensive [NetBeans tutorial](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html), [this Sun tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/WebServices/restful/) and maybe having at look at the [Restlet](http://www.restlet.org/) framework.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [RESTlet in Action](http://www.restlet.org/documentation/books) to learn about REST concepts. It's an early access book so only the first few chapters are currently available, but I found the writing to be very clear.