# Writing first RESTFul Webservice and Client

Tags: web-services, rest, jboss7.x, maven-3, webservice-client

Guys I almost spent a day on googling to find step by step tutorial for writing my first RESTFul service. No Luck

My environment is as follow

- JDK 1.7
- JBoss 713
- Maven
- Eclipse Indigo

Any pointer will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: You will find everything in the internet. Please first do a good research and then only ask question relating to a particular problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DropWizard provides end-end easy solution to write and deploy REST Services. Really impressive.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. Though "RESTFul Java with JAX-RS" is quite old and lot of things evolved current past, gives good insight on the concepts. As Surya explained you need to go though multiple resources to get a good understanding on REST. [What's the best source for learning how to create RESTful APIs in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2840275/whats-the-best-source-for-learning-how-to-create-restful-apis-in-java)